# Photos in the Camera folder in the Gallery were deleted automatically in my Android phone

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, storage, gallery, images, samsung-galaxy-core-prime

I am wondering about how it is possible that all the pictures in the Camera folder in the Gallery were deleted without my knowledge where I am the only user of my Android phone. I don't remember exactly how many pictures were there in the camera folder that I have been capturing for almost six months. But they were there till the last night and only this morning I was shocked to have discovered the deletion.Although I know there are many software through which I can recover my photos,I want to know the possible causes behind.Is it due to the maximum size of photos that can be kept in the camera folder in the Gallery,surpassing which may trigger automatic deletion of the photos or just something else? If so,then how do I manage the size or number of photos? My phone is not rooted. Any advice is welcome!

The screenshots of my device memory is:

[image: Screenshot_Storage_1] [image: Screenshot_Storage_2]

<sup>Screenshot - Storage (Click to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: I doubt that any system function would trigger such an "automatic deletion": if there's "no space left", that would at maximum trigger an error message, so it must be something else. If you're lucky, you might still find a hint [in the logs](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info).

Comment: I have found many previously sent images in WhatsApp now which confirms that images has not been deleted. But the matter is that the images are not shown in the gallery. What should I do to recover image? @Izzy

Comment: Can you check with a [file explorer](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_fileman) whether the photos exist somewhere else then in WA? They are usually stored below `/sdcard/DCIM`. It could be that just your [media-scanner](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/media-scanner/info) had a hick-up. If you can confirm the files are there, we can take a look into that.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments you said:

> *I have found many previously sent images in WhatsApp now which confirms that images has not been deleted. But the matter is that the images are not shown in the gallery. What should I do to recover image?*

So you are telling me that the images are still on your phone, but not deleted? If that is the case it may be cause of a `.nomedia` file in the same folder as your photos.

You should check in your whatsapp folder and look for a `.nomedia` file. (`/Whatsapp/`).
And for your photos you made with the camera app, you should look in `/DCIM/Camera/` (you can do that e.g. using the "My Files" app which is pre-installed on your device; the `.nomedia` files could be in `DCIM` or in `DCIM/Camera` – ignore other locations for now). 
If you find a `.nomedia` file in one of these directories, then you should delete the file and then your photos should appear again in your gallery. If you still don't see the photos after you deleted the file, reboot your phone.

Hope my answer helps! If there is no `.nomedia` file, leave a comment below so I can help you further.

Comment: In the device storage> DCIM there are two subfolders namely thumbnails and camera are present. But camera folder shows 0 items :(.  device storage> android>data shows .nomedia file, in whatsapp>sent folder there is also .nomedia file, but in the images folder there is no such .nomedia file @SuperThomasLab

Comment: @rosemary And in that images folder, do you see your photos?